# tab completion for scrapy crawl command

Tags: python, scrapy

In a scrapy project with multiple spiders, the tab completion when typing `scrapy crawl <spider_name>` is painfully slow (~5 seconds). Is there any way to disable tab completion just when trying to run `scrapy crawl`?

Comment: Try this: `import readline; `[`readline.set_completer(None)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/readline#readline.set_completer) or `readline.parse_and_bind('tab:')`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I noticed a readline.parse_and_bind('tab:complete') in the scrapy source code. Where could I put that would override the default behavior?

Comment: sorry, in my answer i confused scrapy with scapy, and didn't notice because both use readline at some point... Unfortunately I don't found a good way to disable completion besides editing the source directly, or disable it when using the shell directly by entering the lines above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that tab completion occurs for arguments of the `scrapy` command is because of [bash_completion](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/316) and `/etc/bash_completion.d/scrapy_bash_completion`, which is part of scrapy.

You can disable tab completion for scrapy by running `complete -r scrapy` (or adding something like that to your `~/.bashrc` file if you never want it).